# "Cannot resolve symbol" when trying to import classes from a jar deployed in my custom maven nexus repo

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, repository, nexus

It's not my first time reading deployed jars from my custom maven nexus repo (my setting.xml is correctly written ), but unfortunately, this time I wasn't able to import classes from a new deployed spring-boot jar, although it does exist in the project classpath.

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'test'
```

ps:  the jar code snippet in my `pom.xml` is as below

```
       <project> 
     ...
        <dependency>
                <groupId>cc.test</groupId>
                <artifactId>jar-name</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.4</version>
            </dependency> 
    ....
 </project>
```

Comment: Do you launch maven update? Does the pom of the jar has the same names (groupId, artifactId, version)? In your IDE, is that jar loaded in classpath?

Comment: @WoAiNii  finally I found a  solution, check out my answer below!

Answer (score 1):

Quick update:

After trying almost everything, I found the solution!
Shortly a  Spring Boot application is not intended to be used as a dependency, thus adding the below configs will generate two separate jars, your application’s executable fat jar will be published with an exec classifier. The normal jar that can be used as a dependency will be unclassified. this  unclassified  jar will be  deployed  in your maven nexus  repo, and  used as a  maven  dependency  in another  spring-boot  project

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <classifier>exec</classifier>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

My  response  is  based  on spring-boot  official documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-an-additional-executable-jar